# Identifying MVC view from SignalR ChatHub

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, signalr

I have a simple chat application that's based on Asp.net `MVC` and `SignalR`. I'm intending to have one `view` per "chat room"
in this application. Every "chat room" is a signalr group. I'm trying to figure out how the server side will know 
that a person is in the specific `view` and then map his/her connectionId to the group. I got an idea of of doing this
in the `OnConnected()` task which gets hit when the user connects to the chathub. It would look something like this:

```
public override async Task OnConnected()
        {
            if("view" == "Room1")
            {
            await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "Room1");
            }
        }
```

But how I would get a hold of the `"view"`? Maybe someone knows a diffrent way to do this?

Here's how most of the View looks currently:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ChatProj.Models.Message>
@using PagedList.Mvc; 
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chat";
}

<h2>Chat</h2>

<style>
ul {list-style-type:circle;}
</style>

<div class="container">



    <div class="nano chat">
        <div class="content">

            <ul id="discussion">
            </ul> 
        </div> 
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="message" />

    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" disabled="disabled" />

    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />

</div>

@section scripts {

    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.nanoscroller.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.--> 
    <script>

        $(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            $(".nano").nanoScroller();
            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                // Add the message to the page. 
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                    + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
            };

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#sendmessage").removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#message').keypress(function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13)
                        $('#sendmessage').click();
                });
            });
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.

            // Set initial focus to message input box.  
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    chat.server.send($('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
        // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the user's `Session` instead? All users with the same `Session` value would be placed in the same "room".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't create separate pages for each chat room but make it a SPA with hub methods to join and leave rooms. That way you don't have to establish a new connection for each room and you can have people in many rooms without getting into conflict with the browser's connection limit (usually 6 concurrent ones per domain).

In any case, to do it your way, you could pass the room name to OnConnected using the [query string](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#querystring):

```
$.connection.hub.qs = { "room": "main" };
....
$.connection.hub.start();
```

and read it in OnConnected:

```
string room = Context.QueryString["room"];
if (room == ...) { ... }
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer mate. Got it working now, just had to change "main" to whatever unique name I wanted for that view. What does SPA stand for by the way? I'm thinking of implementing a /join group commannd into the application so it's possible to join/create any group. I created specific pages for each group so that it's more intuitive to users. But not needed.

Comment: @JazzMaster [Single Page Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), i.e. you could switch rooms without a full page reload